# How to loop a div which has a dynamic class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I add a class to a link which is generated by code. I am using `jQuery` to do this. I got this code:

```
var e = 0;

$('a.topopup3').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('link' + e++);
});
```

And now I want to use `.each()` function to loop these link tags. I tried this:

```
$('.link' + e).each(function(){
    alert('.link' + e);
});
```

But it doesn't alert anything. I think I'm doing something totally wrong, can someone please give me a hint?

Comment: why do you need the class name to end with a unique number?  What are you trying to do that wouldn't work by just `$(this).addClass('link')`?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? There's no need to loop each '.link' + e, you know which elements have that class, because you selected them previously in order to add the class - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/kzKXs/12/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [attribute start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for looping to select elements that start with `link` :

```
$('[class^=link]').each(function(){
 alert('.link' + $(this).index());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B6zFR/4/)**

Comment: Try this is a terrible explanation

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't alert anything. For what is that `^` in `[class=^link]`? And the class isn't just `.link`. It is `.link0` up to `.link23`. For each div a class which counts itself up

Comment: think it should be `$('[class^="link"]')`

Comment: @shakib: that is only required when you have special character in attribute which needs to be escaped.

Comment: I'm very confused now. In the demo it is working and I do the very same thing as in the fiddle. In firebug I see that the classes exist but when I try to use your code it doesn't alert. And I call your code after I create the classes so it should work...

Comment: @Therk this won't work because your elements' `class` doesn't start with `link`, they already have the class `topopup3`

Comment: Ah. So I have to use `$('[class^="topopup3 link"]')`?

Comment: `$(this).index()` is always 0. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: @billyonecan and what would be the ideal way? :)

Comment: @Therk i don't know because i'm struggling to understand what it is that you're trying to achieve :p

Comment: Ahh it's to much to explain in a comment ;) But do you know why `$(this).index()` is always 0?

Comment: @Therk probably because you're getting the index of the element relative to its parent, rather than the index within the current collection

Comment: Ah okay, I changed it to `'.link' + e` and its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The Other option could be not adding a class instead adding an id

var e = 0;

```
    $('a.topopup3').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('id' ,+e++);
     });
```

Then you can call them as:

```
   $('a.topopup3').each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
```

hope it helps